# in Middleware IIB/ACE how to parse huge JSON messages and insert them into DB

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

in Middleware IIB/ACE how to parse huge JSON messages and insert them into DB

rather hitting every time into DB. how to parse json messages into records and insert in DB table

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will need to use the **aggregate nodes**. You may find the official documentation of the Message Flow Aggregation in the following link https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/9.0.0?topic=aggregation-message-flow
I also found the below tutorial useful but I it is explaining how to aggregate messages from different resources but you can adapt the solution as per your requirements.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNJ6fHHj_as

Comment: is it possible to send a json message to DB using SP and there we can write a loop for each record to insert into table

Comment: Of course it is possible and in this case I suggest that you make the column's type at database to be CLOB as you said the JSON is huge.

Comment: thanks for the information. can you suggest to me that is it possible that can we to send bulk insert statements like 500 insert statements to oracle DB from IIB using esql.if yes can you please help me here thanks in adavance